# Download multiple files in a zip folder from server side location in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have a location path with multiple pdf's in a folder. Onclick of a button i want to zip all the pdfs in a zip folder and download.

can anyone suggest any good approach for handling entire scenario?

I am able to download only single file using:

```
         <Link
            to="/files/List.pdf"
            target="_blank"
            download
          >
            Download Template
          </Link>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to perform these operations in the browser. Better create an API.